# Unable to download file from S3

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have an EC2 instance with S3 FullAccess roles attached to it,
The instance is in a Public subnet in my VPC.

I have **installed AWS CLI on the EC2 instance** using the following commands -

```
$ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

I **verified the AWS CLI installation** using the following command -

```
$ aws help
```

I could list the S3 Buckets using the following command -

```
$ aws s3 ls
```

I have a file uploaded on S3 inside a prefix location, 
I tried to download it using the following command -

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket demoBucketName --key demoFolder/demoFile.php demoFile.php
```

I got the following error for the above command -
[image]

I also tried with -

```
aws s3 cp s3://demoBucketName/demoFolder/demoFile.php demoFile.php
```

Got this error for the 2nd command -
[image]

Comment: Error messages are crystal clear.

Comment: Will I need to aws configure even after attaching the Role to the instance? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket BUCKET
```

Let's assume that the output of above command is `us-west-2`.

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket demoBucketName --key --region us-west-2 demoFolder/demoFile.php demoFile.php
```

Comment: Why do we need to specify the region? S3 buckets are global right?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje : Because you are attempting to operate on a bucket in a region that requires Signature version 4. You can fix this issue by  explicitly providing correct region location using `--region` argument.

Comment: oh alright, could you tell me what if I want to download a .jar from the S3 location, will I do the same?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje : I am not sure. Why don't you try  yourself ?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje no, buckets are not global.  The bucket *namespace* is global (bucket names must be globally unique), and the S3 console is "global," since it requires no region selection, but each bucket is in a specific region, which is selected when the bucket is created.

Comment: @Shravan40 It worked to get the .jar file too, thanks for your help

Comment: In my specific use case I was assuming the role from one aws account to another and even when specifying the version it still failed. I was able to fix this by setting the correct region when assuming the role.